# Ecommerce UX: is a step-by-step product configuration better than a one-click purchase?

Tags: e-commerce, multi-step, multiple-products, product-details

I have a pretty complex software product with lots of appendances and different logics to support and I was wondering, given the user will need at least some level of guidance about what the product is/does and what they can buy/configure before buying, do you think in your experience a "step-by-step" product configuration is needed? Would it perform better than a single product page or product comparison table with all the info for each different product "package" and a single CTA?

I'm on the fence about the cost involved with the first solution so I would love someone else's point of view here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first scenario, you'll have to measure [Hicks-Hyman Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law) very carefully, since you'll have a loss of engagement and abandonment will grow. How much? Well, that's what you'll need to measure.

> Hick's law, or the Hick–Hyman law, named after British and American
> psychologists William Edmund Hick and Ray Hyman, describes the time it
> takes for a person to make a decision as a result of the possible
> choices: increasing the number of choices will increase the decision
> time logarithmically. The Hick–Hyman law assesses cognitive
> information capacity in choice reaction experiments. The amount of
> time taken to process a certain amount of bits in the Hick–Hyman law
> is known as the rate of gain of information.

So, you'll need to ask yourself what does it take to allow for customer's automatic customization, and what does it take to create preset packages. Obviously, preset packages will be faster, cheaper and easier to maintain.

But if you have to spend a lot of time in customer support for features that might be tehre (or not), or if you notice that features' preference is scattered between your target audience, then you might be better spending a bit more of time and allow for customization

Of course, you can simply study user behavior and create incremental packages where the more important and desired features are in a more expensive package, while most common features are in a basic package. I'm sure you have seen this many times before. If you're interested on this aspect, you can read about [pricing psychology](https://www.helpscout.com/blog/pricing-strategies/)

Answer (score 2):

One argument against selling a complex product with one click buy is customers buying the wrong thing because they did not fully understand what they were buying.

And given your product complexity as described...

> ...pretty complex software product with lots of appendances and different logics to support ...

it sounds like you do need to create more of a step by step process for users who need to understand the product.  Of course, the ones that already understand it would find this cumbersome.

To that end, I'd make both - step by step for those that need to understand better, and one click for those that don't.

Comment: I would say that ones that already understand are probably the ones that have already bought it. Best just to stick with the one wizard process I think.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative view is measuring how having to choose so many options impacts conversion. This is data that can be brought up to decision makers to rethink how the product is sold. How much business are you turning away by requiring customizations before vs after conversion?